Why is it possible to create a model with a ManyToManyField without providing a value for the ManyToManyField?
As every field in django model is required. So how when creating an object of model which is having a field with many to many relationship to another model. We can create this model object without specifying many-to-many field value ?
I am talking about when writing query like ModelName.objects.create() not about while working with forms or modelforms.

Why would every field be required?

@willeM_VanOnsem It is by default in django that every field is required but to make a field optional we have to specify null=true. But many-to-many does have this behaviour we can just add model instance without value for many-to-many field. Why ?

that's not null, that's empty. For BooleanFields it is not required either, since that would mean you have to always check the item.

@willeM_VanOnsem please read my question i am asking about many-to-many field. Please answer it if you can.

no, you say "every field in Django". But that premise is wrong.


As every field in Django model is required.

I reject this premise. Not every field is required. A field with blank=True [Django-doc] means you don't have to write a value in the form. But even if blank=False, this applies to model forms, serializers, model admin, not the model layer itself. For a BooleanField model field [Django-doc] this is by default not the case, since that would require that you always check the checkbox (which is what required=True means for a BooleanField form field [Django-doc]). This is indeed implemented like [GitHub]:

class BooleanField(Field):
    # …

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        if self.choices is not None:
            include_blank = not (self.has_default() or 'initial' in kwargs)
            defaults = {'choices': self.get_choices(include_blank=include_blank)}
        else:
            form_class = (
                forms.NullBooleanField if self.null else forms.BooleanField
            )
            # In HTML checkboxes, 'required' means "must be checked" which is
            # different from the choices case ("must select some value").
            # required=False allows unchecked checkboxes.
            defaults = {'form_class': form_class, 'required': False}
        return super().formfield(**{**defaults, **kwargs})

For a ManyToManyField, making it required thus would mean you have to select at least one item. But this is often not what is intended: a ManyToManyField means an item can point to zero, one or more items. It also does not set something to NULL in case there are no items, NULL and an empty collection are two different things.
More important for the model layer, you can not easily provide a value for it. This is a result of how Django implements many-to-many fields: with a junction table. It thus creates an extra table with ForeignKeys to the first and second model. This thus means that it can only populate the junction table after the first record is created. This logic is encapsulated in a ModelForm which does both the model and its ManyToManyFields and thus in case of a create first makes the record, and then saves the junction table records; or in case of an update, not only updates the Post record, but also the junction table between Post and Tags.
Essentially this thus means that a ManyToManyField deals with an extra model. You can even work with that model directly. Indeed, if you have a model:
class Tag(models.Model):
    pass


class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
You can get that model as:
Post.tags.through
and for example remove all connections between all Posts and all Tags with:
Post.tags.through.objects.all().delete()

I respect your knowledge and thank you for sharing this valuable knowledge but my questions is different. It is that while writing query like Post.objects.create() i have to pass  value for each field and let's say i have a field which is many-to-many relationship with other model tags. But while writing the query i have to pass value for every field like title, content & published date. But passing value for tags field which is many-to-many is optional and query works without passing tags value why ? Is this because django creates another table to handle many to many relaitonship.

@Simar: no, make for example a Post object, with a field title = models.CharField(max_length=128), and even without specifying the title, it will create one.

But what if i set null=False and blank=False. Will it also works. I don't think so because by default null=False and blank=True for every field. And it not works in my code.

@Simar: blank has not much to do with the model. It only is usefull for ModelForms, ModelSerializers, ModelResources and other products that are derived from the model that for example interact with the user. blank=True makes no difference w.r.t. the database table, nor the interaction on the model layer.

@Simar If you found Willem's answer helpful, please upvote and accept.
